# How to attach POIs in wikitude with google map places

Tags: google-maps, android, geolocation, augmented-reality

I want to create android application which uses AR and using camera it found the different stores around it and highlight it as display in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjWcS.jpg). I am using wikitude sdk(javascript API) and android studio.I have created app like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CHfW.jpg). I want attach all these POI markers with google map places.How to do that?